# Regular Expression do not allow ROMAN numbers in text box javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input text box which should allow alphabets, numbers and spaces but it should not allow ROMAN Numbers like I V C X.

Please validate if a word has only ROMAN numbers in it then we should not allow it.

Here's the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zdyz3vee/1/)

```
var regex1 = new RegExp("^((?!sr|jr|I|V|X).)*$");
```

Please help.

[Roman Numbers list](http://romannumerals.babuo.com/roman-numerals-1-3000)

Comment: Why do you need someone else to do it? You even provided a fiddle link yourself...

Comment: If I write `I like turtles` in your text box, how do you plan to know if the `I` is a word or a roman numeral?

Comment: @Vache that would be `first like turtle` :P

Comment: What is `sr`, `jr` ?

Comment: Its a name field and we do not want to allow Roman numbers in the name. For example, if any one provided Louis IV then we should not allow it. Actually you guys should get a client like mine, then you would understand

Comment: Sr and Jr is Senior and Junior.. @Avinash Raj

Comment: We only need to check at the last word of the name whether its a roman number or not...

Comment: Scrap the regex. Split the string into words and then validate the last. If it contains only I V C X L M characters then throw error, else it is fine

Comment: @tinku try this http://regex101.com/r/qM0hE6/1 regex.

Comment: It's Working. Thank you so much Avinash!!! You are wonderful and so quick!! @AvinashRaj

Comment: Great Question ElGavilan!! You really are a vilan, its in your name.. I don't know how to do that, so I asked @ElGavilan

Comment: How can I do if my name is `VI`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+)?(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(?:(?![IVXLCMD]|sr|jr)[A-Za-z0-9])+$
```

Comment: You are a regex KING!! It is not allowing to give +1 for the answer as I do not have 15 reputation to do so. I'm so sorry for that..